# Analytic function map semicircular region bijectively to unit ball?

Tags: complex-analysis

Find an analytic function
$f: Ω\to\mathbb{C}$
which takes the semicircular region
$Ω =\{z\in\mathbf{C}:|z|<1,\text{Im} z >0\}$ one-to-one and onto the unit ball
$B_1(0) =\{z\in\mathbf{C}:|z|<1\}.$

My idea is let $f(z)=z^2$, but it seems the real segment [0,1) is missing. Is there any other function satisfying the requirement?

Answer (score 1):

The mapping $$h: \Omega \longrightarrow Q_1, z \mapsto i \ \frac{1-z}{1+z}$$ maps the domain $\Omega$ conformally onto the first quadrant $Q_1 := \{ z = x + iy \in \mathbb{C} \ | \ x, y > 0 \}$. Subsequently, the mapping $z \mapsto z^2$ sends $Q_1$ conformally onto the upper half plane $UH := \{ z = x + iy \ | \ y > 0 \}$. Finally, the mapping $$g: UH \longrightarrow B_1(0), z \mapsto \frac{z-i}{z+i}$$ maps $UH$ conformally onto the unit disk $B_1(0)$. Hence the composed mapping $$f := g \circ z^2 \circ h: \Omega \longrightarrow B_1(0)$$ is the desired mapping you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am new to this area. I wonder if there are some references/tricks about functions of the form $\frac{az-b}{cz-d}$? For example, how could I know they map some special area to some other special area?

Comment: You're totally right, there are indeed "some references/tricks" on functions of the form you mentioned: mappings $$\frac{az-b}{cz-d}$$ with $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{C}$ satisfying $ad-bc \not = 0$ are called *Möbius transformations*, they play a crucial role in complex analysis and in particular in geometric function theory. Another reference I would recommend you to check is the *Cayley transform*, which is nothing else but the mapping $g(z) = \frac{z-i}{z+i}$ i mentioned in my answer - it is a fundamental result that $g$ maps the upper half plane conformally onto the unit disk.